# Octaves vs Decades Fractions

Tags: power-spectral-density, octave

At this [USGS](http://jclahr.com/science/psn/wielandt/node28.html) very good site about rms noise in sensors, a phrase regarding third octave bands (the original topic) appeared.

> The figure displays the minimum vertical seismic noise directly as **rms** amplitudes in a bandwidth of **one-sixth decade**. By coincidence, these amplitudes may also be interpreted as average **peak** amplitudes in a bandwidth of **one-third octave** (a standard bandwidth in acoustics)

One sixth decade factor is $10^{1/6}=1.467799$; the 10th factor $10/6=1.666666$, and one third octave factor $2^{1/3}=1.259921$, none of them being comparable.

It happens actually to be comparable with one tenth decade factor $10^{1/10}=1.258925$.

Note the rms and peak distictions... Why the author state as coincident both log factors?

[image]

In addition, the same paragraph continues with:

> An example: the minimum vertical ground noise between the periods of 10 and 20 sec is at -180 dB relative to  ${\rm 1 m/s^2}$, thus  ${\rm 10^{-180/20}\;m/s^2 = 1\;nm/s^2}$ average peak in one-third octave.

Which is ok, but then:

> Since the bandwidth considered is a full octave, the total average peak amplitude in this band is  ${\rm\sqrt{3}\;nm/s^2}$.

In here i honestly dont know why a $\sqrt 3$ factor appeared...

Answer (score 1):

I think they made a mistake. $2^{1/3} \approx 1.259921$ is not close enough to $10^{1/6} \approx 1.467799$ to say that there is any coincidence. Even the half-octave factor $2^{1/2} \approx 1.414214$ is closer.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to compare $2^{1/3}=1.259921$ and $10^{1/10}=1.258925$ which are more nearly comparable: $$\left(2^{1/3}\right)^{10} = \left(2^{10}\right)^{1/3} \approx \left(10^3\right)^{1/3} = 10\implies 2^{1/3} \approx 10^{1/10}$$

Comment: @DilipSarwate the source does not mention $10^{1/10}.$

Comment: You are right; it is the OP who observed the similarity of the two numbers and the source is incorrect, as you already told her.

Comment: The author compares the decade result as rms value while the octave result as peak value. Besides in the published website, they imply a $\sqrt 3$ factor, which got me completely lost in there....

Comment: That factor comes from that if each third of the octave of interest have 1 nm/s² "average peak", which is some sort of an amplitude quantity (similar to RMS), then they sum as $\sqrt{1 + 1 + 1}$ nm/s² average peak if the noises in the three bands are independent.

Comment: the reason 1/3 octave is about 1/10 decade is because $2^{10} \approx 10^3$.  we sometimes use the symbol "K" (as in "kilo") to mean either.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson That's right. The underlying connection can be described by that each $2^{10} = 10^a$ and $2^{1/a} =  10^{1/10}$ solve as $a = \frac{10\ln(2)}{\ln(10)} \approx 3.010299956 \approx 3.$